# Port forwarding my router

Tags: networking, home-networking, port-forwarding

I am trying run a web server on my static IP address but when I open my IP address its opening my DSL router how can I assign that IP to my computer

any ideas?

Comment: Your static IP address is Global or Private address? If you want to access your local server. Use `http://localhost`

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your router to provide one of the following

- DMZ facility in which you specify that your internal machine is inside the DMZ (for every port or a port range)
- a NATting that maps your external address to your internal machine (choose if just a PAT for webserver or a 1:1)

This will allow external connection going to your router IP to reach your machine. From inside the network just use your local IP

Comment: NAT -- DMZ Host

The DSL router will forward IP packets from the WAN that do not belong to any of the applications configured in the Virtual Servers table to the DMZ host computer.

Enter the computer's IP address and click "Apply" to activate the DMZ host.

Clear the IP address field and click "Apply" to deactivate the DMZ host.

i added my ip address but its still going to router any idea? i added my computer ip address

Comment: Which IP address ?

Answer (score 0):

Use either of these:

1. setup virtual server and forward port to webserverip (system ip) in router configuration.
2. like @livetolearn said: configure webserver ip in DMZ host option in router configuration.

Both will work.

Eg:
webserver ip is your system ip like 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.1.254
router ip is 192.168.1.1.
log in to 192.168.1.1 put user name and password then configure with choice of option mentioned above