# assign router ip address to web server

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, web

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [assign router ip address to web server](https://superuser.com/questions/201550/assign-router-ip-address-to-web-server)
>   [Port forwarding my router](https://superuser.com/questions/201510/port-forwarding-my-router)

I have apache web server installed on my computer and I have a static ip address but when I open that address my router admin is opening how can I assign that IP direct to my computer so my server can be accessible via my IP address

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/201510/port-forwarding-my-router and http://superuser.com/questions/201550/assign-router-ip-address-to-web-server ?

Comment: you do not need to post a new question on the site if the previous site you have posted it on was closed as off-topic and migrated.  The question will move over for you.

Comment: that was a mistake i dont post question again and again i am sorry about that

Comment: I understand your desire to find an answer right away, but answers take time and research.  Instead of filling up this page with comments, move over to the chat and talk there, or wait until answers can be given to you.  Also for future reference, give as much info as you can relating to the question.  The higher the quality the question the higher the quality the answer you will get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not ip address related but rather port forwarding related.  You have to forward the port range of the apache server from the router to the server. (Which as qroberts stated is port 80)

Comment: thanks for you reply  how can i do that i try to add my ip address in NAT -- DMZ Host
192.168.1.51 but not working how can i forward that to my apache server

Comment: @livetolearn what router are you using? is it flashed to dd-wrt or any other os?

Comment: Board ID: 96338E-MT 
Software Version: EchoLife HG510V100R001C05B026.T.A2pB021a.d16f 
Bootloader (CFE) Version: cfe.d010.1102

Comment: @livetolearn we need the model and make

Comment: AN1020-16T and screen shot http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/6421/123s.png

Answer (score 0):

Change the remote administration port of your router from 80 to something different.

Forward port 80 on your router to point to the IP address of the machine where the apache server is located.

Comment: and where from i can change that? in router i cant find any port Forward menu can you guide plz

Comment: What is the model/make of your router? Did you want to DMZ the server where apache is installed?

Comment: Without knowing the exact router you have it's impossible to give detailed instructions,  have you tried searching your routers manual for port forwarding?

Comment: 119.152.53.65 here you go you can now change in my router

Comment: I would strongly advise NOT posting that on a public website. I cannot access it from here. It may be my works policy or it isn't allowing remote connections. Someone else give it a shot?

Comment: @livetolearn that's not exactly the smartest idea.  You should delete that comment... you don't really know who we are... I've tried and failed as well @qroberts

Comment: something happen to it its changed now layout is changed in my router

Comment: yes sorry i found it can only be access from lan and my ip is changed now can you guide me now thanks

Comment: I will need the _name_ and the _model_ number of the router in order to give a detailed description.

Comment: AN1020-16T screen shot http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/6421/123s.png